# How can I ensure only the root user have the right to halt/reboot the system?

Tags: centos, permissions, shutdown, reboot

CentOS Linux by default allows all users to have permission to "halt" & "reboot" the system by using the commands `halt` and `reboot`.

How can I configure my system so that only the root user has the right to `halt`/`reboot` the system?

Comment: Remove SUID-bit from `halt` and `reboot`.

Comment: Don't remove the suid bit, otherwise a normal user logged in at the console can't reboot the system. Leave the permissions as they are. The programs already have logic to let only the superuser or the console user run these commands successfully.

Answer (score 2):

#### CentOS/RHEL/Fedora

You can disable access to these commands by removing their entries in the `/etc/security/console.apps/*`:

```
$ $ ls /etc/security/console.apps/
authconfig      gparted          poweroff                      system-config-date      system-config-network-cmd  zenmap-root
authconfig-gtk  halt             reboot                        system-config-keyboard  system-config-selinux
authconfig-tui  kismet_capture   setup                         system-config-language  system-config-users
chkrootkit      liveusb-creator  system-config-authentication  system-config-lvm       wifi-radar
config-util     lshw-gui         system-config-boot            system-config-network   wireshark

$ rm -f /etc/security/console.apps/reboot
```

Above was found here: [27.2. Disabling Console Program Access - CentOS Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-access-console-program.html)

#### Hack method

I think you can achieve this by doing the following. In the directory `/lib/upstart`, are the following commands:

```
$ pwd
/lib/upstart

$ ls -la
total 176
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Sep  9  2011 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 16 root root 12288 May  4 21:27 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     6 May 26  2011 halt -> reboot
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     6 May 26  2011 poweroff -> reboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 17112 May 11  2011 reboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 14472 May 11  2011 runlevel
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 65976 May 11  2011 shutdown
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 56304 May 11  2011 telinit
```

chmod 700 the reboot executable:

```
$ chmod 700 /lib/upstart/reboot
```

Comment: You don't really ever want to change modes of system files like this.

Comment: Why not? Show me a source that says this!

Comment: Because if you change modes, the 'rpm -V' commands gets cranky with you and tells you you have a potentially corrupted system. That's what the RPM database is for - to make sure critical files like these don't have their permissions bits changed unexpectedly.

Comment: @John I do that all the time. One big example is that I remove world execute from `su`. It's important to verify that various changes don't break anything, but this would only break something if a core system script was both running as non-root (unlikely) and called the `reboot` binary directly (also unlikely). I haven't tested this specific change but "don't change modes on system files" isn't a valid general principle in my experience.

Comment: @John - yeah thanks I know what the RPM database is for. It will only complain if that package is ever updates which is part of the `usermode` package which I don't think will be getting rev'd too much. Your argument is total bunk. The system can be managed however it makes sense as the operator/owner.

Comment: See my updates, there is the "official" way to to remove the commands from access for the users.

Comment: @slm - the "rpm -V" command will complain when permissions are changed. It doesn't have to have a package update to complain. An update to that package will silently replace the permissions to 755, defeating the purpose of changing the permissions unless the manager changes permissions every time updates are applied.

Comment: Not all warnings need to be acted upon. There is such a thing as expected failures. Making file permissions more restrictive is a core part of OS hardening. Generally, there's some mechanism for dealing with OS updates. Where I work, I have a cronjob that runs every five minutes that issues appropriate `setfacl` and `chmod` commands (in case someone manually makes permissions more liberal and doesn't reset them) other places use IDS tools like Tripwire to ensure continued compliance.

Comment: @John - Yup I know about the rpm -V, it doesn't take any action, it just reports that file is inconsistent with the original RPM, again so what. There are lots of files that are not going to pass this test. Sendmail for example. As I said before, I wouldn't expect a lot of churn on that RPM! For example: F14 box: Build Date: Tue 05 Oct 2010, Install Date: Sat 18 Dec 2010. I can provide CentOS & RHEL box info that shows the same pattern.

Comment: We do the same thing @JoelDavis with the cron. To conform to PCI for taking credit cards you need to guarantee that filesystem permissions remain consistent. I've seen it done in that space too. The point here is that the RPM DB is another tool to help, it isn't the gospel.

Answer (score 1):

These commands already force you to either be root or be logged in to the console. If a normal user runs "halt" or "reboot" from an ssh session, it refuses to halt or reboot the system:

`$ halt

halt: must be superuser.`

Comment: Reboot doesn't! I use that all the time as a non-root user on my laptop!

Comment: And you're logged in tot he console of your laptop when you issue that command, so you should be able to issue that command. When SSH'ed in to a system as a non-root user, if you issue the reboot command, you will be told "reboot: must be superuser."

Comment: The requirement in the OP is that only the root user can initiate a reboot. System defaults leave open the possibility that non-root users can execute if they have CAP_SYS_BOOT. Your user likely doesn't have that capability configured for it so that's why it's erroring out ("must be superuser" is just a helpful message given how most platforms are set up by default).