# halt, poweroff, shutdown, reboot don't require root?

Tags: permissions, users

For some reason, I can run `halt`, `poweroff`, `shutdown`, and `reboot` as a regular user without root. How can I fix this? Is it something to do with user groups, or is it a seting somewhere?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80492/how-can-i-ensure-only-the-root-user-have-the-right-to-halt-reboot-the-system

Comment: This is a distribution dependent question, which are you running?

Comment: @msw Arch Linux

Comment: It is not an error, so you don't have to fix it, you would like to change it but I see no need since if two users are logged on the system you WILL NEED root permission to shut it down.

Answer (score 1):

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Power_management
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Actions

It seems on Arch Linux that if you install polkit, and your are the only "common user" online on the system(local user through systemd-logind ), you can execute the shutdown/poweroff/reboot commands without root password.

Otherwise, you will be asked for the root password.

Comment: Further reading : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209839/5132