# What are the default Polkit privileges on Arch Linux for shutdown, halt, etc., and why are they so?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, polkit

On Arch Linux, with systemd, the following commands are all symlinks to `systemctl`:

```
/usr/bin/telinit
/usr/bin/poweroff
/usr/bin/runlevel
/usr/bin/reboot
/usr/bin/halt
/usr/bin/shutdown
```

I find their behaviour with respect to authorization confusing:

```
$ shutdown
Must be root.
$ halt
Must be root.
$ telinit 3
# Asks for Polkit authorization
```

Neither `poweroff` nor `reboot` asks for authorization. `poweroff` doesn't actually turn off my system, the laptop remains on with text on the screen stating it is powering off - indefinitely.

I haven't tinkered with Polkit rules, so I wonder why their behaviour is so.

- All commands were tried with my non-root admin user, who's a member of `wheel`.
- `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` only seems to contain a default ruleset:

  ```
  # tail /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/*
  // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, it will be overwritten on update
  //
  // Default rules for polkit
  //
  // See the polkit(8) man page for more information
  // about configuring polkit.

  polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
      return ["unix-group:wheel"];
  });
  ```

On closer inspection, `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy` has sections for `poweroff`, `reboot`, `suspend` and `hibernate`, with `allow_active` set to yes. But there are no sections for `shutdown`. If this is the cause, why is it so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty complicated. Let's explain the commands in order you've enumerated them.

1. `telinit`

   Various arguments to `telinit` directly translate to various (different) subcommands of `systemctl`. As per [telinit(8)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/telinit.html) (documentation from systemd package):

   > 2, 3, 4, 5
   >
   > Change the SysV runlevel. This is translated into an activation request for `runlevel2.target`, `runlevel3.target`, ... and is equivalent to `systemctl isolate runlevel2.target`, `systemctl isolate runlevel3.target`, ...

   So, these commands translate to `systemctl isolate`, which itself is governed by polkit action `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units`. Privileges for that action default to **requiring admin authentication** — both for active sessions, inactive sessions and processes outside of any session.

   *(BTW, by default polkit is configured such that it treats any user in `wheel` group as an admin. Thus you were prompted to authenticate for yourself.)*
2. `halt`, `poweroff`, `reboot`

   Commands `poweroff` and `reboot` work in two steps:

   - if invoked under a non-root-user and `logind` is available, `logind` is asked to perform the action, using polkit actions `org.freedesktop.login1.*`;
   - otherwise, the almost-equivalent of `systemctl poweroff` or `systemctl reboot` is executed, but **without consulting polkit**.

   `halt` is similar, but it always goes the second route (almost-equivalent of `systemctl halt`). There is no method for halting via logind.

   Note the "almost-equivalent". In case you do

   - `poweroff` under a non-root without logind,
   - `reboot` under a non-root without logind,
   - `halt` under a non-root,

   you get a "Must be root." instead of authenticating for `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units` via polkit. At the same time, with `systemctl poweroff`, `systemctl reboot` or `systemctl halt` you will be given a chance to authenticate via polkit. This is probably a bug.
3. `shutdown`

   This tool can be used to schedule a delayed poweroff, halt or reboot. If invoked without arguments, a delay of 1 minute is implied. The default action is power-off. From [shutdown(8)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/shutdown.html#Description):

   > The time string may either be in the format "hh:mm" for hour/minutes specifying the time to execute the shutdown at, specified in 24h clock format. Alternatively it may be in the syntax "+m" referring to the specified number of minutes m from now. "now" is an alias for "+0", i.e. for triggering an immediate shutdown. If no time argument is specified, "+1" is implied.

   If timeout and wall message are not specified, `shutdown` is equivalent to one of `poweroff`, `halt` or `reboot` (see #2).

   If either a timeout or a wall message is specified, `shutdown` requires root privileges.
4. `poweroff` doesn't power off

   It really should. This is probably a kernel bug.

Comment: Excellent answer. So, I take it in my case, `shutdown` behaves like `halt` instead of `poweroff` when used without timeouts/messages. Both `shutdown` and `halt` seem to turn off my system.

Comment: `shutdown` defaults to "poweroff with timeout"... so are you saying that `shutdown` powers it off, but `poweroff` doesn't?

Comment: Ah.. Never mind. Turns out I can't get a consistent behaviour across any of them. Probably a bug that will get fixed by inaction. At any rate, it did lead me to this question, so even bugs have their uses.

Comment: @muru: for `systemctl %s` vs halt/reboot/poweroff: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/213

Comment: I didn't realize you were a systemd dev. Nice! :D Poettering's comment has a key phrase: "default behaviour".  As you probably know, some tools can detect if they're run in a TTY, and change behaviour accordingly. Hopefully some day these tools will too.

Comment: Bump: since your PR was merged, some of this can be updated?

Comment: @muru It appears that systemctl behavior has changed again since then. `poweroff`, `halt` and friends now seem to be able to use interactive auth again. But TBH I haven't been following systemd development so closely these days, so I can't tell what exactly was changed and why.

Comment: Further reading : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289123/5132