# Is the `reboot` command safe to use?

Tags: linux, reboot

The `reboot` command appears to work differently depending on the distribution.

For example on Ubuntu/Debian and CentOS it shuts down services first while on Arch Linux it reboots immediately (at least with my setup).

Is it always safe to use `reboot`?

Comment: Since `reboot` in Arch Linux is [actually `systemctl`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209766/70524), I strongly doubt it doesn't stop services.

Comment: @muru so that means it's always safe to use? If I `sudo reboot` on Arch I see the boot screen in ~0 secs.

Comment: If in doubt, just use `init 6`.

Comment: @laktak I see it in a couple of seconds, but usually faster than in, say Ubuntu. It depends on what you run and what you're running it on.

Comment: As far as I understand, the safest command should be `shutdown -r`. Could someone confirm that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a very good explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/46158)

> The BSD halt and reboot commands were low-level, drastic, and immediate. The considerate way to shut down a BSD system was the shutdown command, which did all of the things that one expects to happen: wall messages to users, services gracefully killed, log entries written, logins disabled, and so forth.

It also explains that on the systemd toolset it always shuts down services first like @muru mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I do remember fairly well the first time I issued an halt in a Solaris server... catastrophic.