# Is 'poweroff' safe?

Tags: linux

So I've been using the command "poweroff" to shut down my Linux system, tried searching only if this is safe or not, mostly people just speak of "shutdown -h now" or something like that. So my question is: Is it safe to shut down Linux using the "poweroff" command?

Comment: `man halt` or `man poweroff`...

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387861/ .

Comment: I've always used `halt` instead, way shorter!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [poweroff](https://linux.die.net/man/8/poweroff) man page:

> When called with --force or when in runlevel 0 or 6, this tool invokes the reboot(2) system call itself and directly reboots the system. **Otherwise this simply invokes the shutdown(8) tool with the appropriate arguments.**

and [shutdown](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown)

> shutdown arranges for the system to be brought down in a safe way.

what this says is simply that... usually `poweroff` calls `shutdown`, so it is pretty much as safe as `shutdown -h now`

Comment: Oh, okay I will